# Regex for text in brackets which contains no specific words

Tags: java, regex

I found some expressions like

```
\((.*?)\)
```

which works good to find any text in brackets with brackets like **(text)**

and

```
^((?!.*(word1|word2|word3)).*)+
```

to find text which contains no one specific word like **word4abcd** and not for **example word1 test**

How to merge them to find text in brackets which not contains these words like in **(example)** and not like **(example word2)**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can there be nested parenthesis?

Comment: I don't think so, anyway it is not very important thing to do for me.

Comment: Do you mean that `(example)` should not match but `(example word2)` should match?

Comment: Can you show us some sample input and output. Do you just want to find out if the string matches or not, or also get the substring that matched?

Comment: Jerry, I meant the opposite. (example) should match and (example word2) should not.

Comment: Rohit Jain, I just want to use it in String.replace(String regex, String replacement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first regular expression uses a reluctant quantifier `*?` to make sure that the first available closing bracket is matched after the opening bracket. The second regular expression uses a zero-width negative look-ahead group (that's the `(?!...)` construction) to prevent matching certain words. To combine these tricks we're looking at something like this:

`\(((?!something).*?)\)`

The question is what goes in the place of the `something`. Simply putting `.*(word1|word2)` there will not work: this will also forbid `word1` or `word2` outside the brackets. Replacing `.*` by `.*?` does not change that. What does work is `[^)]*(word1|word2)` which will match any sequence of characters unequal to `)` followed by `word1` or `word2`.

The resultant expression then is

`\(((?![^)]*(word1|word2)).*?)\)`

which will match a bracketed expression that does not contain `word1` or `word2`.

Answer (score 0):

Question isn't very clear but I am giving an example that might help you.

Look at this regex:

```
/\((?!.*?\bexample\s+word\b[^)]*\)).*?\bexample\b.*?\)/
```

This matches word `example` inside square brackets. match will happen if there is no `example word` in the square brackets.

`\b` has been used for word boundaries so that `examples` is not matched instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this it what you want?

```
^\(((?!.*word1)(\S)*)|(\3)\)
```

Match:         (wordwordexample)
Not Match:     (word wordexample)
               (word1wordexample)